# Laravel uniquewith-validator package nullable function won't work

Tags: laravel, unique

I'm using uniquewith-validator packageand I manage to set not to allow these three combination: name, last_name and telephone. The problem is when I want to enter same name and last_name but without telephone. When telephone is empty or null it says it's duplicate but if I change telephone it allows it as it should. I need to allow that but in this code it doesn't:

```
'name' => 'required|unique_with:add_members, last_name, telephone'
```

When I make one column unique I use nullable function but here it doesn't work...

I use nullable when I make one column unique and this is working:

```
's_number' => 'nullable|unique:add_members'
```

How to allow telephone to be nullable and not to count as duplicate?

This is my full code in AddMemberRequest.php

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'          => 'required|nullable|unique_with:add_members, last_name, telephone',
        'last_name'     => 'required',
        's_number'      => 'nullable|unique:add_members',
        'street'        => 'nullable|unique_with:add_members, name, last_name, number',
    ];
}
```

Comment: can you post your full rules array?

Comment: If you mean full code in request file then ok, I added ;)

Comment: Do you have unique indexes on your database table? Something like `$table->string('telephone')->unique()` or `$table->unique('name', 'last_name', 'telephone')`?

Comment: No, I did not put it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded when I changed the attribute. Instead of name attribute that I allready use when I set to be required I add telephone attribute to be unique in combination with name and last_name and to be nullable. Like this:

```
'telephone_1'   => 'nullable|unique_with:add_members, name, last_name',
```

And full rules function now is:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        's_number' => 'nullable|unique:add_members',
        'telephone_1' => 'nullable|unique_with:add_members, name, last_name',
        'street' => 'nullable|unique_with:add_members, name, last_name, number',
    ];
}
```

I hope somebody will be helpful this solution.