# Validate two unique columns

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.8

I have a model `Market` which can have an owner and many customers. When a customer registers I want to validate that they are unique based on the `email` and `customer_market_id`. I would like a customer to be able to register with the same email as the market owner. The difference is that the market owner has `null` for the `customer_market_id`. When I try to do that with my current validation it fails.

`email => ['unique:users,email,customer_market_id'`]

I have tried this approach with the `uniquewith-validation` package:

`email => ['unique_with:users,customer_market_id']`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this following link out if it could help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330619/laravel-uniquewith-validator-package-nullable-function-wont-work

Answer (score 0):

```
'email' => 'unique:table_name,email_address_column'
```

unique takes two argument. The first argument is table_name in your database and the second one is column_name in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try following in your validation:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email | unique:users,customer_market_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

For different user role registration you can use **laravel Guard**. create guard for each role type like owner and customer and can easily register both with same ids. [Laravel Guard](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards)
see documentation